# Adding Layout to a ViewGroup Android

Tags: android, android-layout, viewgroup

I have a flying in menu which based on ViewGroup.
I want that there will be a basic layout and in any activity i would be able to insert to the view group new layout and afterwards to erase it.
**But it doesn't work!!!** Can you help me please.

class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.root = (FlyOutContainer) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

    this.setAdditionalLayout(findViewById(R.id.physical_layout));

    this.setContentView(root);
}
```

ViewGroup:

```
    <com.nurielweizmann.calculator.view.viewgroup.FlyOutContainer xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                              android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#444488"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/menu">
............
</RelativeLayout>
</com.nurielweizmann.calculator.view.viewgroup.FlyOutContainer>
```

Function:

```
    FlyOutContainer root;
    public void setAdditionalLayout(View view){
        root.addView(view,1);
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the `setContentView(int)` instead of the `onCreate(Bundle)`.

Make sure your base layout XML has a `ViewGroup` (`FrameLayout`, for example) available to put each `Activity`'s content.

When overriding the `setContentView(int)`, inflate your base layout first then inflate the `Activity`'s layout and place the `Activity`'s layout on the `FrameLayout` available.